# ZooKeeper Timeout - Cannot find myid file. Windows Server 2016

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have very simple setup. I am trying to start ZooKeeper (apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin) on two machines. I get following error when i do zookeeper status

```
 /cygdrive/c/ZooKeeper/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin
$ bin/zkServer.sh restart
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: C:\ZooKeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: C:\ZooKeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg
Stopping zookeeper ... STOPPED
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: C:\ZooKeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED

kalsa@CO01EAP00000027 /cygdrive/c/ZooKeeper/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin
$ bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: C:\ZooKeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg
cat: '/tmp/zookeeper/'$'\r''/myid': No such file or directory
clientPort not found and myid could not be determined. Terminating.
```

My Zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=5000
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=XYZ:2888:3888
server.2=ABC:2888:3888
```

I have proper IPs in place of XYZ and ABC.

I have created myid file created as well. Can someone let me know if i am missing anything obvious
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCnwb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The owner of datadir should be the zookeeper user. If not, change the owner.